# Application closes on pressing power button - React-Native Android

Tags: android, performance, react-native

When I press the power button of an Android Phone, while an application developed using react-native, and wake up the phone again, the application has closed.

I was not able to find any reason or any solution for this. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1 
>    // MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnPowerPressed() {
        moveTaskToPower(true);

}
```

> Step 2:

```
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<activity
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

i dont Develop in react but hope this help you to create the idea. Usually you should create a method to override bugs like yours. Good luck

Comment: Thank you @SmAster. I had already added the android:launchMode="singleTop" in my manifest.